# Flutter sharedpreferences setString method is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am trying to keep some user information but setString method is not working.

when i call the setString method, method is not even creating those keys.
I tried to write methods several time, watched some videos and my code became a mess. Can you help me somehow?

Here is my code page

```
import 'package:falci_cadi/util/app_constant.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Profil extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilState createState() => _ProfilState();
}

class _ProfilState extends State<Profil> {
  var formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  setName(String name) async {
    SharedPreferences mySf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    mySf.setString('isim2', name);
  }

  setSurName(String surname) async {
    SharedPreferences mySf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    mySf.setString('soyisim', surname);
  }

  setMail(String mail) async {
    SharedPreferences mySf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    mySf.setString('mail', mail);
  }

  setMeslek(String meslek) async {
    SharedPreferences mySf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    mySf.setString('meslek', meslek);
  }

  setAsk(String ask) async {
    SharedPreferences mySf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    mySf.setString('ask', ask);
  }

  Future<String> getName() async {
    SharedPreferences mySf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String isim = mySf.getString('isim2') ?? "nulllllll";
    return isim;
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getName().then(updateName);
  }

  updateName(String s) {
    setState(() {
      AppConstant.name2 = s;
    });
  }

  List<String> ask = <String>[
    'İlişki Durumunuz',
    'Evli',
    'İlişkisi Yok',
    'Platonik',
    'Karmaşık',
    'Flört Halinde',
    'İlişkisi Var',
    'Yeni Ayrılmış',
    'Nişanlı',
    'Dul',
    'Boşanmış',
    'Ayrı Yaşıyor',
  ];

  List<String> meslekler = <String>[
    "Mesleğiniz",
    "Ev Hanımı",
    "Çalışmıyor",
    "İş Arıyor",
    "Öğrenci",
    "Kendi işini yapıyor",
    "Kamu sektörü",
    "Özel sektör",
    'Emekli',
  ];

  String baslik = AppConstant.name2 + " " + AppConstant.surName2;
  String altBaslik =
      AppConstant.meslek2 + "," + AppConstant.love2 + "," + AppConstant.mail2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          'PROFİL',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white70,
            fontSize: 44,
            // fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('images/profil.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  15.0,
                ),
//                  color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent
              ),
              child: Form(
                key: formkey,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text(AppConstant.name2 +
                                  " " +
                                  AppConstant.surName2),
                              subtitle: Text(AppConstant.meslek2 +
                                  "," +
                                  AppConstant.love2 +
                                  "," +
                                  AppConstant.mail2),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onSaved: (deger) {
                          setState(() {
                            setName(deger);
                          });
                        },
                        scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "  Adınızı Girin",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onSaved: (deger) {
                          setState(() {
                            setSurName(deger);
                          });
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "  Soyadınızı Girin",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onSaved: (deger) {
                          setState(() {
                            setMail(deger);
                          });
                        },
                        cursorRadius: Radius.circular(15),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "  E-posta Adresinizi Girin",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          underline: Text(""),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: meslekler[0],
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              setMeslek(newValue);
                            });
                          },
                          items: meslekler
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          underline: Text(""),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: ask[0],
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              setAsk(newValue);
                            });
                          },
                          items:
                              ask.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Center(child: Text("KAYDET")))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just want to save some input and get them wherever i want. Since i couldn't get the name i didn't even bother myself with writng other gets. I would be very grateful if you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 Future<void> setName() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString("Name", "whatEver name");

  }

Future<String> getString() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    name = prefs.getString("Name") ?? "null";

    return name;
  }
```

and to get the string in widget tree use future Builder.

```
return FutureBuilder(
        future: getString(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<UserInfo> snapshot) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Future<void> setString(String key, String value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(key,value);
  }
```